# correctly setup AWS RDS for local mysql migration, MySQLdump

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to setup AWS RDS and it seems that I am still missing something.  I am getting an error message from the mysql command (step 2) which I found on this SO, [Trying to migrate local mysql server to AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573287/trying-to-migrate-local-mysql-server-to-aws)

```
mysql -h [endpoint] -u [user] -p [dbname] < dumpfilename.sql

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myfishdb.blahblah.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)
```

Here is my RDS inbound:

```
MYSQL    TCP    3306    sg-2928d04c (awseb-e-blahblah-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-FTX0Z7AKRHZ2)
SSH    TCP    22    72.xxx.xx.226/32
```

I am running maverick os local and the AWS is a free tier account.

Comment: Are you running in classic or VPC?

Comment: I am running it in VPC.  This is the message I received in the RDS dashboard in the security group menu option: "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms and Using RDS in VPC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RDS Security group allows access on port 3306 only from `sg-2928d04c1`. So ensure that the instance on which you are running the `mysql` command has this security group applied.

Also, As you have mentioned that `Here is my RDS inbound:`, I would presume this is the RDS security group that you are referring to. So if this is the case, I would again presume that you running RDS in EC2-classic and **NOT** inside a VPC. If this is not the case, then provide more information on your RDs deployment.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, your presumption is correct.  I am new to AWS and don't know about their security layout.  I simply want to upload my MySQL database to AWS so that my django web app can serve the content.  What do I need to do to accomplish this?  I suppose I can write a new question and get more help since it looks like this might be off topic.